# jQuery only works for first half of document; Uncaught ReferenceError in second half

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first half of my JS document works correctly (and uses jQuery), but the second half does not. On the console, it displays:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at app.js:20

Line 20 is where the `$(document)` starts.

In the HTML, I have the jQuery reference at the end of my document:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
```

Here is my complete app.js:

```js
/* responding to width change*/
const mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)');

mq.addListener(WidthChange);

function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        $('nav').removeClass('affix');
        $('nav').addClass('upper');
        $('li').css('display', 'inline');
    }
    else {
        $('nav').addClass('affix');
        $('nav').removeClass('upper');
        $('li').css('display','');
    }
};

/* navigating*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2').on('click', function(evt) {
        $('h2').css('color', 'red');
        console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

To reiterate, the first half of the file is tested and working, only the second half seems to have trouble identifying the JQuery selector.

Comment: Is your JQuery insert the first javascript you insert?

Comment: The issue is because jQuery is not defined in the page correctly. I can see your script reference, so either the path is wrong, or you're putting it in the wrong place

Comment: jQuery needs to be loaded prior to any usage.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the calling of the script file.

You need to call `<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>` before you write `ready function`.

```js
/* responding to width change*/
const mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)');

mq.addListener(WidthChange);

function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        $('nav').removeClass('affix');
        $('nav').addClass('upper');
        $('li').css('display', 'inline');
    }
    else {
        $('nav').addClass('affix');
        $('nav').removeClass('upper');
        $('li').css('display','');
    }
};

/* navigating*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2').on('click', function(evt) {
        $('h2').css('color', 'red');
        console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the answer in your question. The reason for this is, jQuery reference at the bottom of the page. When used inside the function, the whole document works as a reference for finding jQuery element, but when using in the page itself, it needs to be imported before it is used, and hence the error.

Comment: I thought that by putting the script tag in HTML I am importing jQuery. How do I make sure it's imported? I am new to programming and I have trouble finding the answers online.

Comment: The best way is to import whatever you need in the file, in the head section of the HTML page. That way it is always ensured that the file is available to use in the body. You can refer [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) for a better insight on this.

Comment: I mean inside a javascript file, if it's being run separately without HTML?

Comment: In a javascript file, you do not need a script tag for importing. And in a javascript file the imports a done always at the top of the file.